# error when returning a value compared to user id

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4, angularfire2

I'm having trouble returning the data based on the user id.

my function is on data.service.ts

```
getData() {
  
  return this.Collection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map( actions => {      
      return actions.map(a => { 
         const userId = a.payload.doc.data().userId;
         const data = a.payload.doc.data();        
         const id = a.payload.doc.id;        
         
      if(userId == this.currentUserId){ return { id, userId, ...data }; }
      
      });      
    })
  );
}
```

it works, but in half a second the following error appears =>

```
core.js:6228 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined
    at InicialPage_ion_item_sliding_17_Template (template.html:42)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:12156)
    at refreshView (core.js:11995)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:13391)
    at refreshView (core.js:12022)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13445)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11716)
    at refreshView (core.js:12051)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:13391)
    at refreshView (core.js:12022)
```

my html code is =>

```
<ion-list lines="none" class="my-ion-list">
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of collection">
    <ion-item >      
      <ion-label>        
        <p>Id do usuario: {{ item.userId }}</p>
        <p>Data: {{ item.dia }}</p>
...
```

can someone help me please

Answer (score 1):

This is because AngularFire `data()` returns `T | undefined`. You must check that data is not `undefined` like this:

```
function getData() {
  return this.Collection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        if (data === undefined) {
          throw new Error('User is not found');
        }
        const userId = data.userId;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;

        if (userId == this.currentUserId) {
          return { id, userId, ...data };
        }
      });
    })
  );
}
```